# show loader while submitting a form

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have the following code which is responsible for submitting a form inside a function load().

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#productfilter").validate({
submitHandler: function(form) {
$.post ('listproresult_core.php', $("#productfilter").serialize(), function(data)   {
$('#contentincore').html(data);
$('#contentincore a').click(function(e) {
$("#contentincore").on("click", "a:not(.minlink)" && "a:not(.prolink)", function ( e ) {
$("#contentincore").load($(this).attr("href"));
e.preventDefault();
}); 
});
});
}
});
});
```

... however, what I want is the response form (while it is loading) to show me the next loader `.gif`.

```
$("#contentincore").html("<img src='loader.gif'class='clock' border='0' />");
```

Comment: What is the purpose of using a validator when there is no rule?

Comment: just place an example before submit loading because I want to show what I ordered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ajax to post your form and you can then execute 'beforeSend'

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "listproresult_core.php",
    data: $("#productfilter").serialize(),

    beforeSend: function() {                                
        $("#contentincore").html("<img src='loader.gif'class='clock' border='0' />");                                       
    }, 

    success: function(result) {                     
        $("#contentincore").html("");        
    }                       
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry, try the code and did not return my response POST , please check the code and make sure it is well written.

Comment: Hi, the code is correct. result is your response from POST. It's up to you to get the code to work within your current system. Maybe you need to double check what variables are being posted

Comment: i refresh the question

Answer (score 0):

1. create a div that contains a img gif of loading.

   look the image of html code[image]
2. in the ready function of the js put the following code:

> ```
>  $('#loadingDiv')
>   .hide()  // hide it initially
>   .ajaxStart(function() {
>       $('#loadingDiv').show();
>   })
>   .ajaxStop(function() {
>       $('#loadingDiv').hide();
>   })
>   .ajaxError(function() {
>       alert('Ajax Error');
>   });
> ```